# Defining multiple variable laravel for use in if statement

Tags: php, url, if-statement, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to be able to display different content depending on which variable is called in the url.Ignoring the fact $slug is slug, let's say it's a post id instead so if $id is active then show just the post else if $month is active show all posts from that month elseif $month and $id = null show all. That's what I'm trying to achive

Routes.php

```
Route::get('blog/{slug}', ['as' => 'blog.slug', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getSlug']);
Route::get('blog/{month}', ['as' => 'blog.slug', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getSlug']);
```

BlogController.php

```
<?php
```

class BlogController extends BaseController {

```
public function BlogIndex()
   {
     //get the posts from the database by asking the Active Record for "all"
    $blogs = Blog::all();
    $blogs = DB::table('blogs')->paginate(3);
    // and create a view which we return - note dot syntax to go into folder
    return View::make('pages.blog', array('blogs' => $blogs));
}
public function ShowbySlug($slug)
{          
       $blogs = Blog::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
// show the view with blog posts (app/views/pages/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('pages.blog')
        ->with('slug', $slug)
        ->with('blogs', $blogs);
}
public function ShowbyMonth($month)
{
       $blogs = Blog::where('month', '=', $month)->get();
// show the view with blog posts (app/views/pages/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('pages.blog')
        ->with('month', $month)
         ->with('blogs', $blogs);
}

}
```

blog.blade.php

```
   @foreach ($blogs as $blog)
  @if(isset($blogs)) 
    <div class="blog-outer-wrap">
    <img src="images/blog/{{ $blog->img}}"> 
     <div class="blog-header">{{ $blog->header }}</div>
    <div class="blog-text">{{ $blog->content }}</div>
    <a href="{{ URL::route('blog.slug', [$blog->slug]) }}">
    </div>

  @elseif(isset($slug)) 
    <div class="blog-outer-wrap">
    <img src="images/blog/{{ $blog->img}}"> 
     <div class="blog-header">{{ $blog->header }}</div>
    <div class="blog-text">{{ $blog->content }}</div>
    </div>
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Use `empty` or `isset` instead of `is_null`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change the content depending which variable is active, am i missing something?

Comment: That's because `blogs` is always set

Comment: is there  way to unset it?

Comment: You're using it, so no. Just do `@if(empty($slug)) .. @else .. @end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't do that, because you just declared the same route twice. When you say a route is `blog/{slug}`, `slug` is only a placeholder. It's exactly the same¹ as `blog/{month}`. All it says is: "I expect `blog/` followed by **anything**." It doesn't matter if you call your *anything* `slug` or `month`. That is, the parameters do not add up.

What you can do is, if you consider `slug` is always a string and `month` is always a number (or the name of the month²), is to apply where clauses to your [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters), like so:

```
// Route for all blog posts
Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@showAll');

// Route for all blog posts in a month; only numbers as parameters
Route::get('blog/{month}', 'BlogController@showByMonth')
     ->where('month', '[0-9]+');

// Route for all blog posts by title; anything else as parameters
Route::get('blog/{slang}', 'BlogController@showBySlang');
```

And on your controller, define three methods, one for each route:

```
public function showAll() {
    $blogs = Blog::all();

    return View::make('pages.blog')
               ->with('blogs', $blogs);
}

public function showByMonth($month) {
    $blogs = Blog::where('month', $month)
                 ->get();

    return View::make('pages.blog')
               ->with('blogs', $blogs);
}

public function showBySlug($slug) {
    $blogs = Blog::where('slug', $slug)
                 ->get();

    return View::make('pages.blog')
               ->with('blogs', $blogs);
}
```

¹ Unless you're using some more advanced routing features, but that's not really the point here.

² It is doable with the where clause, but it would be ugly if you wanted to consider all upper/lower case combinations. E.g: `([Jj][Aa][Nn][Uu][Aa][Rr][Yy]|[Ff][Ee][Bb][Rr][Uu][Aa][Rr][Yy]|...)`

Comment: Right got you, so I have updated my routes and now need to update my blogcontroller.Currently looks like the below but I keep getting undefined variable blogs presumably because it's not passing the variable. How do i go about this? (updated blog controller in questions)

Comment: You'll need 3 methods in your controller: `showAll`, `showByMonth` and `showBySlang`. One for each route.

Comment: You're passing the wrong parameters to the view. You should always pass `$blogs`.

Comment: Thanks guys, now working as it should be however i need to display different content depending on which page is active, how would i do this? I have updated with my blog.blade.php code. Undefined variable: slug (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\pages\blog.blade.php)